# How to parse text into Enum with Jackson stream API vary on different enum class at runtime?

Tags: java, enums, stream, jackson

I want to use Jackson stream api to parse POJO which contains Enums at runtime, like this:

```
Class<Enum<?>> enumClass = field.getType();
JsonParser parser = ...;
String s = parser.getValueAsString();
Enum enum = (Enum)isThereAnyBiFunctionCanGetDynamicEnum(s, enumClass);
```

Can I mix the DataBind and Stream API solution, i.e. use `ObjectReader` to get `Enum`:

```
ObjectReader reader = ...;
Enum enum = (Enum)reader.readValue(parser, enumClass);
```

I feel this might not be a good practice, can someone please guide.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `org.apache.commons.lang3.EnumUtils` class and [getEnum](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/EnumUtils.html#getEnum(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String)) method:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.EnumUtils;

public class EnumApp {

    enum Type {
        INT,
        STRING
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(EnumUtils.getEnum(Type.class, "INT"));
        System.out.println(EnumUtils.getEnum(Type.class, "STRING"));
        System.out.println(EnumUtils.getEnum(Type.class, "STRING1"));
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
INT
STRING
null
```

But using `ObjectMapper` `API` by calling:

```
reader.readValue(parser, enumClass);
```

is also OK and there is nothing wrong with it.